# Exactly one computer has an extremely slow connection to exactly one network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, internet

Speedtest shows less than 1 Mbps on one computer despite another computer connected to the same router from the same place getting 25 Mbps. I've had a similar issue with the same computer before, (using a different router) but the problem somehow resolved itself overnight, before I got too deep into troubleshooting.

Further details:

- Connection speed is fine when connecting to another wireless network. Whatever the problem is, it's unique to this particular device on this particular network.
- Connecting through an ethernet cable or through wireless makes no difference.
- Windows Network Diagnostics sometimes fails to identify a problem, sometimes says "Your computer appears to be correctly configured, but the device or resource (DNS Server) is not responding" On rare occasions it also says that the default gateway was not available, but that that problem has been resolved.
- Pinging the default gateway results in a response time anywhere from 20 to 160 ms, with roughly 20% of pings lost entirely.

Things I have tried:

- Restarted the computer
- Assigned IP address, DNS, and default gateway automatically
- Released and renewed IP
- Assigned default gateway manually
- Assigned DNS manually
- Assigned static IP
- Checked for new drivers using the windows automatic utility.
- Manually downloaded and installed driver from manufacturer.

None of these efforts resulted in any change whatsoever. I've pretty much gone as far as I can using my limited knowledge of computers and extensive knowledge of Google, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Fixed by resetting the wireless range extender. No idea why that worked.

Comment: Instances like this are a pain. You've covered the **Wired** (Ethernet) and **Wireless** hardware and protocols, any specific peripheral or device driver issues should not have affected the two separate devices the same way. So, you've crossed off two separate networking hardware states. **Virus: Is it infected?** Here are a few options that may help you out: 1. OS version and/or Services Packs installed? 2. Hardware or system specs/brand(have you checked the motherboard for bad CAPS? (capacitors) So is the underlying hardware bad?

Comment: 3.     **Have you tried booting from a Linux distro. DVD or USB drive? If you get the same issue running a bootable Linux system then you've likely narrowed it down to the system hardware.**

The last option would be capturing the data coming from this systems network connection or do a full format and reinstall the OS.

Comment: Twinblaze what antivirus do you run? Some suites intercept the network stack and cause all sorts of strange behavior that could cause this. In any case its software so a clean install should resolve it as a last resort.

Comment: Try resetting the ip stack. Run the following commands in a cmd shell: `netsh int ip reset`, then `netsh winsock reset` and finally `netsh advfirewall reset`

Comment: So I ended up fixing the problem by sheer luck, although I'm still not entirely clear what the problem was. In the beginning I had been operating under the assumption that the problem was with the computer itself, as the other computer was connecting just fine. But out of desperation, I started trying anything I could think of. After more fruitless efforts, I reset the wireless range extender, and suddenly everything worked fine. I have no idea how or why that fixed the problem, but at least it's fixed.